# VBA reference workbook open on an other computer with path?

Tags: database, vba, reference

Good day all,

Here's the situation, I have an excel file that I use as a database(connected to an sql database). This file is open on a computer in the server room, and is periodically saved in the shared drive (I can access it from any computer within the company). I need to read data from that file and store them in arrays. When opened on my computer, I can simply reference it with : `wkb = Excel.Workbooks("Dashboard DataBase.xlsm")`, but opened on a different computer I can't. I know the path where it is saving, is there a way for me to use the path as reference?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure how VBA handles UNC paths, but if you have the path, you use it just like you are doing now. So instead of `wkb = Excel.Workbooks("Dashboard DataBase.xlsm")` you would use something like `wkb = Excel.Workbooks("X:\Folder\Dashboard DataBase.xlsm")` where X is a mapped network drive.   May also be able to use the UNC path `\\serverName\shareFolder\Dashboard Database.xlsm`

Comment: Tried it but gives me subscript out of rang?

Comment: Does that error occur on the `wkb =` line?  What is your updated `wkb =` line look like now. You can obfuscate any private details with "Folder" or something.  Also on this `different computer` can you manually navigate to the file and open it?  That computer will also need access to the file. There's no way to circumvent security measures.

Comment: Yes on the wkb line: Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("\\mnl03\data$\Shared\Public\Folder\Saw trackers\Dashboard DataBase.xlsm")    Yes on the different computer I can freely navigate and open files. Could I for example import the data from that file the same way you can create a connection to an sql database but without needing to copy them in a spreadsheet? The reason behind is the amount of lines. The database dumps 100k+ lines of data, and I want to only showcase yesterday and today data. Maybe I am not taking the right approach?

Comment: update: if I use FName = "\\mnl03\data$\Shared\Public\Folder\Saw trackers\Dashboard DataBase.xlsm"
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(FName) It will open the file, from this I understand it is able to access it?

Comment: Yep. If that opens the file you should be able to use that same string to "access" the file during code execution. And yes, depending on how you have your data formatted within the target excel sheet you can connect to it and query for the data you want to import. There's quite a few topics on that exact scenario running around here.

Comment: Great thanks, I will look further into it!